# Emacs GDB does not load shared library symbols

Tags: libraries, c, gdb

I am trying to debug a C/MPI library that I have built. All objects are compiled using GCC and `-ggdb`, they are also linked using `-ggdb`.

When I try to attach a gdb session to the process with the `-p PID` flag from a standard shell, I have no problems. I can debug and access all source file info.

However, when I invoke a GDB session in Emacs 24.3.1, GDB reports that it cannot load my shared library:

```
 warning: Could not load shared library symbols for ./libllg.so.
```

I noticed that Emacs called GDB with the flag `-i=mi` is this causing the problem?

Everything is exactly the same, the symbol is found from a normal bash shell but not from the emacs GDB implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your shell configuration file have any customizatins of where shared libraries are stored? Like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? If so, Emacs may not be loading your configuration and you would need to do that yourself, for example via `(setenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ...)`.

Comment: Given that it says "./libllg.so", I would suspect that the pwd differs and that this makes a difference.

Comment: Did you try running gdb by doing: `C-U M-x gdb` ? That way you can pass your own flag, including the `-p PID`.  Also did you try with `gud-gdb`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @wvxvw you were right it was an issue with the library path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this was an issue with my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which contained a relative path.

Emacs GDB launches with the working directory equal to that of the buffer you are in when you call the file.

That means that in order to load a library from `./` I had to make sure that I was in that directory when launching the debugger. The shared library was then loaded correctly.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Fixed by running `cd /` which effectively turned all relative paths into absolute ones.